# How to retrieve int value from EditText

Tags: android

I have two  text box and i have simple array,
all i want to do is to wright the array index number in the text box one, and get the array value in the text box two when i click the "claculate" button.

here is my "MainActivity.java" code:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    final EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    public void onClick(View v) {

    final int[] oil={20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
    final String str = String.valueOf(R.id.editText1);
    final int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
    final int z = oil[y];

    ET2.setText(z);
    }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    }
```

here is my "activity_main.xml" code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Calculate" />
```

Comment: For writing an `int` into the EditText, do `ET2.setText(""+z);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            EditText searchtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);

            String copy = searchtext.getText().toString());
```

and to get

```
     EditText etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchtext2);
     etSearch.setText(copy);
```

Comment: I got this:

Bundle[{searchtext=2}]

when i type "2"

Comment: I got "searchtext" in searchtext2 when i type any thing

Comment: thanks, its work now:

i do this:

EditText searchtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String copy = searchtext.getText().toString();
 final Integer y = Integer.valueOf(copy);
              
EditText etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 etSearch.setText(""+oil[y]);

Answer (score 2):

You can just convert the string contained in the edittext to int, and do whatever you need with:

```
EditText editText = null;//Your edittext
try{
int number = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){editText.setHint("Invalid number...");}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a try catch statement. It's a lot more efficient if you don't.
First, you need to check that the EditText contains an integer and is not empty. Use this function:

```
public static boolean IsInteger(String s)
{
   if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return false;
   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
      if (Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10) < 0)
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Then:

```
if (editText.getText().toString() != "" && IsInteger(editText.getText().toString())
    int number = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: so, according to you is more efficient to iterate through all the digits, than letting the os catch the Exception? An exception that is being checked just for best practices because if you see the xml, is set as "numeric" which will not allow to set any non digit character in...

Comment: @martin Personally I disagree with this answer and set the restrictions at the UI level. If I know that the user can only enter numeric characters, then it is safe to use `Integer.valueOf()` without any further checks. Of course, I am also starting to use Test Driven Development. By writing tests first before writing this code, you can have further confidence that it is correct.

Comment: i get this:

"The method IsInteger cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type"

Comment: My code is more efficient than using a `try catch` statement, but I agree, if the user can only enter numbers and you are sure that it is in the right format, then it isn't necessary to check that it is an integer.